# Problem in creating side-by-side images (Pure HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, image

[image: side-by-side image]

I have problem in vertical space between Up and down portfolio row.
I have some unwanted space in rows
It's not margin or padding in box, i think this problem is for img tag
Can anyone help me?

```css
.portfolio.row {
display: flex;
}
.col-4 {
  flex: 33.33%;
}
.portfolio > div img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio row">
  <div class="col-4" id="coffe">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/07/16/19/strawberry-4186310_960_720.jpg" alt="Nature1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" id="coffe">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/07/16/19/strawberry-4186310_960_720.jpg" alt="Nature2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" id="coffe">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/07/16/19/strawberry-4186310_960_720.jpg" alt="Nature3">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="portfolio row">
  <div class="col-4" id="work">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/07/16/19/strawberry-4186310_960_720.jpg" alt="Nature1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" id="work">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/07/16/19/strawberry-4186310_960_720.jpg" alt="Nature2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" id="work">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/07/16/19/strawberry-4186310_960_720.jpg" alt="Nature3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that it's trying to keep the aspect ratio of the images. If you add `height: 100%` it does work:

```css
.portfolio.row {
display: flex;
}
.col-4 {
  flex: 33.33%;
}
.portfolio > div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio row">
  <div class="col-4" id="coffe">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/07/16/19/strawberry-4186310_960_720.jpg" alt="Nature1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" id="coffe">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/07/16/19/strawberry-4186310_960_720.jpg" alt="Nature2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" id="coffe">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/07/16/19/strawberry-4186310_960_720.jpg" alt="Nature3">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="portfolio row">
  <div class="col-4" id="work">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/07/16/19/strawberry-4186310_960_720.jpg" alt="Nature1">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" id="work">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/07/16/19/strawberry-4186310_960_720.jpg" alt="Nature2">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4" id="work">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2019/05/07/16/19/strawberry-4186310_960_720.jpg" alt="Nature3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @MohammadKiyan then what is it that you're looking for?

Answer (score -1):

Just use the following code and it will be fixed! `height: 100%;` will solve your problem. here is [example](https://codepen.io/mobarak/pen/ZNOMmW)

```
.portfolio>div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;  /* Add this extar value */
}
```

Comment: What does this add to the other answer?

Comment: I did not see your answer while preparing my answer. But after I published mine found you are there!